# What is the time complexity of a recursive function that spawns n - (i + 2) function calls on each iteration?

Tags: python, algorithm, performance, recursion

I'm working on a DP problem called house robber, I've solved the problem using a DP approach but my initial thought was to use the following recursive function:

```
def rec(self, start, possible):
        if len(possible) == 0:
            return start
        
        money = start
        for i, num in enumerate(possible):
            nextMoney = self.rec(start + num, possible[i+2:])   
            money = max(money, nextMoney)
            
        return money
            
            
    def rob(self, nums: List[int]) -> int:
        # Base Case
        if(len(nums) == 0):
            return 0
        elif len(nums) == 1:
            return nums[0]
        
        path1 = self.rec(nums[0], nums[2:])
        path2 = self.rec(nums[1], nums[3:])
        
        # Recursion
        return max(path1, path2)
```

My DP solution is O(n) but I'm struggling to determine the time complexity of the algorithm described above. My instinct says its of exponential order to the log(n) = O(n ^ log (n))

If anyone can point me in the right direction here that would be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Problem for reference: https://leetcode.com/problems/house-robber/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code enumerates all subsets of 1..n with no two adjacent numbers. You do lots of slicing of `possible` which creates an O(n^2) cost per call, so the recurrence relation is:

```
T(n) = n^2 + sum(T(i) for i=0..n-2)
```

Subtracting T(n) from T(n-1):

```
T(n) - T(n-1) = n^2 - (n-1)^2 + T(n-2)
T(n) = 2n - 1 + T(n-1) + T(n-2)
```

Let `U(n) = T(n) + 2n + 5`, so `T(n) = U(n) - 2n - 5`. Substituting for `T(n)`, `T(n-1)` and `T(n-2)` we get:

```
U(n) - 2n - 5 = 2n - 1 + U(n-1) - 2(n-1) - 5 + U(n-2) - 2(n-2) - 5
U(n) = U(n-1) + U(n-2) (simplifying)
```

so U(n) = Fib(n) (ie: fibonacci numbers), and T(n) = Fib(n) - 2n - 5.

So your runtime is Theta(Fib(n)), which is Theta(phi^n), where phi is the golden ratio.

[An interesting note is that if you removed the list slicing that causes the O(n^2) cost per call, the complexity class of your code would be the same -- the cost of slicing is lost in the otherwise exponential cost of the code].

Comment: @templatetypedef I got the sign wrong (fixed now), and I added a step into the explanation. Does it make sense?

Comment: Great, thanks! I was not expecting to see Fibonacci numbers here!

Comment: The fibonacci numbers appear naturally because the number of subsets of {1...n} with no two consecutive numbers is Fib(n+2).

Comment: Oh yeah! That makes a ton of sense. I forgot about Zeckendorf’s theorem and results like that. My initial hunch was that this would be something like n!!, but I forgot that we’re significantly shrinking per call.